# Execution order with Out-GridView - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I started to run function with Out-GridView but the order is very important to me, when I mark first for example the function4 and then function1 the function4 is excited first
How can I fix the order?

```
function function1 {
    Write-Host "Number 1"
}

function function2 {
    Write-Host "Number 2"
}

function function3 {
    Write-Host "Number 3"
}

function function4 {
    Write-Host "Number 4"
}

$functions = "function1", "function2", "function3", "function4"

$chooses = $functions | Out-GridView -PassThru

foreach ($choose in $chooses) {
    & $choose 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could associate your functions with some sort of priority table that way, after selection, you can sort them back into the correct priority order no matter the selection order, for instance:

```
$functions = [ordered]@{
    'function1' = 1
    'function2' = 2
    'function3' = 3
    'function4' = 4
}

$chooses = $functions.Keys | Out-GridView -PassThru | Sort-Object { $functions[$_] }

foreach ($choose in $chooses) {
    & $choose
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that works with simple array. Start from the original array of functions and *filter* by using the selection array in a `Where-Object` condition.

```bash
$functions = "function1", "function2", "function3", "function4"

$chooses = $functions | Out-GridView -PassThru

$functions | Where-Object { $_ -in $chooses } | ForEach-Object { & $_ }
```

The last line could be made more succinct using the `.Where{}` and `.ForEach{}` [intrinsic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#methods-of-arrays):

```bash
$functions.Where{ $_ -in $chooses }.ForEach{ & $_ }
```

Both `Where-Object` and `.Where{}` method work similarly. They apply the condition of the scriptblock to each element of the `$functions` array and output only those elements for which the condition evaluates to `$true`. So they act as a filter.

In the condition, the `-in` operator tests if the current (`$_`) element of `$functions` is contained in the `$chooses` array. In this case it evaluates to `$true` and the element will be passed on to `ForEach-Object` or `.ForEach{}` method.

Here is another way, using plain old `foreach` loop, which is functionally equivalent to the previous code samples:

```bash
foreach( $fun in $functions ) {
    if( $fun -in $chooses ) {
        & $fun
    }
}
```

As an alternative to the `-in` operator you could also use `-contains`, which requires to swap the operands:

```bash
    if( $chooses -contains $fun )
```

Comment: Thank you @zett42
can you explain how its work?

Comment: @Bandit I've added explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I meant how it solved my issue with the ordering, the first answer is clear to me

Comment: @Bandit It solves it because we are iterating over the `$functions` array instead of the `$chooses` array. The `$functions` array is already in order.

Comment: @Bandit I've also added a `foreach` loop example, which uses the same principle and might be easier to understand.